# Get multiple row counts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a illustration of my table.

```
id    |  stocks  | colour
0156  |   in     |  red
5482  |  out     |  red
5488  |  out     | yellow
```

I need to get 3 row counts. How is it possible to the 3 different types of COUNT values in a query?

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM tbl, 
        (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl WHERE stock = 'out'),
        (SELECT count(*) FROM tbl WHERE colour= 'yellow')";
$statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$val_tot = $row[0]; //?
```

Comment: What are 'three types of COUNT'? There are only two COUNT in your example. Do you want to group count values by stocks, do you?

Comment: It *doesn't* work the way you think it is.

Comment: @max Thanks. I need to get the `total rows` and count of `in` stocks and count of `yellow` colour